# blender can't read the .txt file

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to draw a cube from the co-ordinates stored in text file it's working just fine when I'm executing it in vs code but my blender text editor keeps giving me 'No such file or directory' error

```
with open("list.txt", "r") as filestream:
for line in filestream:
  currentline = line.split(",")
  total = str( int(currentline[0]) + int(currentline[1]) + int(currentline[2])) + "\n"
 
  print(currentline)[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide the absolute path to the txt file, because blender python shell may not have its working directory in the directory containing the txt file.

EDIT
You could try to import the `os` module and call `os.chdir("/directory/containing/the/txt/file/")` before opening the txt file.